# Bounty and Reputations Relationship

Tags: support, reputation, bounty

I know that bounty can be started up by offering Reputation.

How much reputation changes to whom bounty awarded?

Is reputation transfers  by bounty from who start bounty and to whom bounty awarded?

In other words, Is **reputations converted in bounty** form who started bounty and **bounty converted in reputation** to whom bounty awarded?

I asked question to avoid my any misunderstanding about bounty and reputation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- If I start a 100 rep bounty, I immediately lose 100 reputation.
- If I award that bounty, the recipient gets an additional 100 reputation.
- If I fail to award the bounty before the time runs out, the highest-scoring new answer (as long as it has a score of 2 or higher) will get 50% of the bounty (so 50 reputation points here) automatically awarded. If there is more than one post that meets that criteria with the same score, the older post gets the bounty.

See more here:

- https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty
- [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)